# React Apex Chart toolbar menu icon z-index is to high. How can I lower it?

Tags: css, reactjs, apexcharts

How can I change the value of the z-index for the icons in the toolbar menu of React Apexchart.

No matter how high I place my element they are always above it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Little bit too late but make sure to add the z-index property (z-index:12 should be enough) to the parent (or the higher parent) of the element you want to display above the apexchart toolbar. I've tried every parent of my element until it worked with a div !

Answer (score 0):

Somewhat late, but still an issue. Not sure why but the z-index of the `apexcharts-toolbar` is 11 by default, so just put this somewhere in your css:

```
.apexcharts-toolbar {
    z-index: 0 !important;
}
```

This might screw up things in certain arrangements of chart displays but so far it has work pretty decent for me.